# Challenging a/b test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, experiment-design

I have a challenging a/b test problem and would appreciate some input.

**Setup:**

We are a company that sells information in a marketplace of buyers - think auction style. We built a predictive model that is hypothesized to improve one of our key metrics. However, instead of building one model, we built n models, one for each buyer, and the model only performs well when we're not dealing with a cold start buyer - not surprising.

**Problem:**

I have to ensure I'm not biasing the test with the design. I say this because some buyers will not be run through the new model since they have no history and will, therefore, be excluded from the 'test variation'. However, they WILL be part of the control variation. If the model performs well, once we completely switch over, we'll deal with new users by defaulting them to the old model.

I have drawn a diagram to illustrate how we are testing the new model on 1% of traffic - we have very large volume.

[image]

**Question**

My question is, with the fact we're excluding some buyers in test variation and including them in control, should we calculate final results excluding those buyers all together? Those buyers could have a different mean and variance and by including them in the final calculation in one version and not the other, I think we could bias the results.

Would love some input on how to deal with this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great question. Your intuition is right -- these new users are likely the hardest ones to predict, so if you remove them from your test set and add them to your control set, this may bias the results in favor of your test set.

Even if you remove these buyers from the test set and completely exclude them from the analysis, you'll still have biased results, because you're letting your test algorithm skip over the "easy" problems but making your control algorithm solve them anyway.

The key is that 1) you need users to be randomly assigned to groups at the start, and 2) you need to make your exclusion criteria the same for both groups. You've got (1) accomplished so now you just need to achieve (2).

I'd suggest you remove all new users from both test AND control sets. For example, you could exclude all data from users with less than $N$ purchases. As you mentioned, you don't need to know how well your algorithm performs for new users; you just want to know how it performs for users with established buying patterns.

(If you're also curious how the models compare for new users, you could perform a separate analysis using new users only.)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you, @CloudyGloudy! Your answer is very helpful. I felt this had to be the right answer and really appreciate your confirmation.